# Finishing (or Accessing) a specific Activity in Android

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo

As Activities are opened by the user, they're stacked up on the view stack.
and as the user finishes an Activity by any means, it is popped out of the view stack.

Now, I have a situation where the user has opened the app's home screen, and has successively opened multiple activities, on top of the home screen. In each activity, there's a control which lets the user see the home screen again.

As i can think, there can be two approaches to get this:

1. On the press of that control, pop the home screen from the bottom of the view stack and push it on the top of it.
2. As the control is pressed, start popping each of the current screen until the home screen becomes the current screen.

I know there's some way in Android to do at least one of this, or something like this.
I just can't remember what was it.

Please help me choose the better approach, and let me know the way (the code, specifically) to do it.

Thanks a lot :)

(Please edit the title/text if it isn't appropriate)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try something like this

```
Intent i = new Intent();
    i.putExtra(EXTRA_KEY_ARTIST, id);
    i.setClass(this, ArtistActivity.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    startActivity(i);
```

That's all when you set the the FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP property it wont start a new activity but will show your activity intially created if its not destroyed yet,

But if your activity is the starting activity then you can put it like this

```
 <activity
    android:name=".ArtistActivity"
    android:label="Artist"
    android:launchMode="singleTop">
</activity>
```

Comment: I could clearly understand the code, but couldn't get what the XML part would mean in the manifest, and the scenario when it'll be useful. Thanks a lot by the way! :-)

Comment: if your activity is the first activity then there is no other place where you can set this singletop using code but using android manifest.xml where you have to use this xml

Comment: Hi, ingsaurabh I want to know what will happen when I press back key after the activity came to top.. :)

Comment: The last activity from which this activty is called is shown but this entirely depends how you are maintaining you activties