# Start and stop activity from parent?

Tags: android, android-intent

I would like be able start and stop another activity from parent, for example if I want show custom dialog as an activity.

So, to start activity I use:

```
private void showIntentDialog() {
    Intent i = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
    ActivityA.this.startActivity(i);    
}
```

But how, how can I handle it with stopping activity?

```
private void stopIntentDialog(){
    //how to finish it ?
}
```

p.s I searched many topics but I couldn't find fitting problem with mine. Most of them has problem to close `B` and back to `A` or return some values.

p.s.s To be clear, I would like start activity `B` from `A` and also after some operations close `B` also from `A`.

Comment: try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4323327/1265724) may help you

Comment: You probably shouldn't use an activity for that (it's not intended to be stopped from another activity)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start Activity as:

```
private void showIntentDialog() {
    Intent i = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    ActivityA.this.startActivity(i);    
}
```

To end activity, send another intent with a boolean flag:

```
private void dismissIntentDialog() {
    Intent i = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    i.putExtra("finish",true);
    ActivityA.this.startActivity(i);
}
```

In target Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent (Intent i){
  if( i.getBooleanExtra("finish",false) ){
     finish();
  }
}
```